# How to add hyperlink to cells in a specific column in excel export in laravel?

Tags: laravel, phpexcel

How to make data in cells in a specific column clickable(hyperlink) in excel export in laravel?

I have tried

```
$sheet->getCell('E26')
    ->getHyperlink()
    ->setUrl('http://examle.com/')
```

this works fine but I don't want to specify cell number. I need it to work for whole column

Comment: A bit more info would be nice. Like what have you tried so far? What where the results? I would expect to find that you just need to enter the url in the field and it should work(if i add https://www.google.com in excel directly, it is already clickable). What are your experiences?

Comment: I tried using for my application sample url will be like(something.subdomain.com/{NAME}/{ID}). The exported excel just displaying the text and I want it to be clickable)

Comment: What if you manually add the url to an excel? Does it become clickable then? If not, could you try to add `http://` or `https://` in front of it?

Comment: Yes I have also tried adding http but it is not clickable

Comment: So manually, it does not become a hyperlink for you? For me it does, what version of excel are you using?

Comment: I opeing it with LibreOffice Im not using MS Excel. Is that a problem?

Comment: Well Libreoffice is Excel-like but not excel, yes that can be a problem

Comment: If you can post a link to an example file, I could try opening it with excel for you and tell you if it works